# ActionListener listens method in different Class

Tags: jsf, tomcat, exception

For some reason tomcat throws an MethodNotFoundException. In my login page,

```
<p:commandButton id="login" value="Log In" action="#{login.go()}" actionListener="#{login.login}" update="panel"/>
```

and my bean ;

```
@ManagedBean(name = "login")
@RequestScoped
public class mbLogin implements Serializable {

//setter getter methods...

public void login(ActionEvent ae) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("i2bORPPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    System.out.println("associ");
    Query qAssociation = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM EntityAssociation a WHERE a.code=:code");
    qAssociation.setParameter("code", code);
    EntityAssociation association = null;
    try {
        association = (EntityAssociation) qAssociation.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Dernek kodu bulunamadı.", null));
        return;
    }
    Query qAuthorized = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM EntityAuthorized a WHERE a.id=:ID");
    qAuthorized.setParameter("ID", association.getAuthorizedID());
    authorizedID = association.getAuthorizedID();

    EntityAuthorized authorized = (EntityAuthorized) qAuthorized.getSingleResult();

    if (!authorized.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username) || !authorized.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış.", null));

    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Helal beee egirdin sonunda", null));
        loggedIn = true;

    }

}

public String go() {
    if (loggedIn) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

        member.setAuthorizedID(authorizedID);
        member.setUsername(username);
        member.setPassword(password);
        member.setCode(code);
        member.setLoggedIn(loggedIn);
        session.setAttribute("login", member);
        return "/Admin/MainPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    return null;

}
```

Here is my problem, Firstly I log in to Admin Panel, there is no problem. After that I go to /Login.xhtml without logout(which I dont invadilate session) and try to log in again with command button in login page. But Tomcat throws this exception

```
02-Aug-2016 00:42:44.075 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-46] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: Admin.User@6b245dd9.login()
at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:268)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:240)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not familiar with this problem but as you can see actionListener listens wrong class. It should be login.login(), not User.login(). Do you have any idea why I have this problem ?

Edit;

[image]

And up there there is an folder called "Admin" inside it "Register.xhtml"

Admin>Register.xhtml

Comment: So, `Admin.User` is also registered with managed bean name "login"?

Comment: User is a normal java class. Its not managed bean and It just has variables like username password id etc. My managedBean classes starts with mb. So mbLogin registered as "login"

Comment: Apparently you're running dirty code. Clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart project and server. Exceptions don't lie.

Comment: I did all, still same exception. Should you think I post more code about my classes ?

Comment: I guess I solve the problem, User and Member are classes which are using by Tomcat. So netbeans had issues  while running project cause of that. I delete my User java class and start to using mbUser for session finally I dont have problem anymore.